# How do I make my header a different color than by body?

Tags: css

When I try to change the color on my header, the color of the body changes as well. I have been trying to change the background also.

```css
head{
color: cyan;
}
body{
color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head color="cyan">
<h1>Hello!</h1>
</head>
<body>
<p> In This you will find.......</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to revisit your learning of HTML. Please read and understand and then you will be able to figure out the misconception here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming error, Its a lack of basic HTML understanding

Comment: You must first learn HTML NOT CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<head></head>` isn't meant for rendering at all ! It is used to define meta data (information about the code itself) and include other resources. I advise you to look into a [html tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) to understand more what the different HTML tags do.

Here is your updated and valid HTML

```css
h1{
color: cyan;
}
p{
color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head color="cyan">
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p> In This you will find.......</p>
  </body>
</html>
```